# Using regex in simple if statements?

Tags: ruby

Instead of doing:

```
puts "what type of input?"
input = gets.chomp
if %W[Int INT i I Ints ints].include?(input) 
puts "enter int"
i = gets.to_i
```

I want to use regex to interpret string user input. For example,

```
puts "are you entering in a string, an int or a float?"
case gets
when /\A(string|s)\z/i
puts "enter in a string"
gets.chomp
when /\A(int|i)\z/i
puts "enter an int"
gets.to_i
when /\A(float|f)\z/i
puts "enter a float"
gets.to_f
end
```

What is the syntax in order to get the same result but using  `if` statements instead of `case` statement?

Comment: `s = gets.chomp; if s.match?(/\A(string|s)\z/i) ...` or `...if s.match(/\A(string|s)\z/i) ...` or `if s =~ /\A(string|s)\z/i ...`. You want `\z`, not `\Z`, for the end-of-string anchor.

Comment: @CarySwoveland how come? They want indeed `\Z` to avoid the necessity to `chomp` upfront.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin, I forgot about `\Z`, or perhaps never knew (no way to know which).

Comment: `\A...\Z` behaves more like `^...$` – both match before an optional line terminator. (which is rarely of interest)

Comment: BTW, why are you asking for an `if` equivalent for that `case` expression? Matching various patterns against a single object is a prime example of using `case`.

Answer (score 2):

`gets` returns a string *with* a trailing carriage return. What you need is to match the ending against `\Z`, not `\z`.

```rb
puts "are you entering in a string, an int or a float?"
case gets
when /\As(tring)?\Z/i
puts "enter in a string"
gets.chomp
when /\Ai(nt)?\Z/i
puts "enter an int"
gets.to_i
when /\Af(loat)?\z/i
puts "enter a float"
gets.to_f
else puts "Didn’t work"
end
```

I also slightly updated regexps to clearly show the intent.

Comment: *"`\Z` - Matches end of string. If string ends with a newline, it matches just before newline"* - [Ruby Doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Anchors)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn your `case` into an `if`, you have to store the expression intended for the `gets` into a variable:

```
response=gets.chomp
if /..../ =~ response
   ...
elsif /.../ =~ response
   ....
....
else
   ...
end
```

Comment: Why would anyone sane want to turn a clean `case` into `elsif` spaghetti?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't say that it is a good idea. Just the OP wanted to know - maybe out of theoretical interest?